# Calculate Week over week performance / Power Query

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerbi, powerquery

I'm new in using Power Query and trying to automate a process to get weekly performance pulling out data from different data sources being sent to me once a week.
Basically, I receive files containing the total overall performance to date from beginning of the season (without showing weekly performance i.e. CW02 performance - CW01 performance easily). I'm currently already able to import files automatically from a specific folder to the query and the file gets updated automatically. 
What I would like to be able to is to have a new column automatically generated and added with the difference between last week and previous week performances. So that every time I save a new file in the folder my analysis gets automatically updated with weekly performance as well.
[Please find here the optimal situation I would like to automatically generate week over week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuGpK.png)

Thank you in advance!

Lorenzo

Comment: Please add some relevant code.

Comment: Honestly you probably should be doing this kind of thing in a pivot table in Excel, or using a matrix table and DAX measures in PowerBI. It is plausible to do in Power Query, but there are other options that are better designed for what you're trying to do.